# Which spell-checker can be used when writing in Latin on a computer?

Tags: contemporary-latin, resource-request, modern-life

So, I am interested, does any spell-checker software today (Aspell, Hunspell...) support Latin? Does it work well enough to be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Murzintcev Nikita mentioned Hunspell in [Latin-Dict](https://latin-dict.github.io/docs/hunspell.html) site.

In addition to the software there mentioned, once we have ".aff" and ".dic" files for Latin (which, to the best of my understanding, are under GPL2 license), we can integrate this in several word processing software including Notepad++ for Windows users. Some time ago I used this in Notepad++ and it worked very good though not perfect as some of the medieval words are not recognized.